# React Route to Page Using Unique ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-router

I have multiple rendered components on a page. When I click on one I want to navigate to a new page with all of the information specific to that component. What I need is:

1. OnClick -> Identify gameId variable
2. Using that gameID run a query against an API endpoint
3. Take the rendered data from the API and display it on a new page with route /nhl/:gameId

Example screenshot of /NHL page with different components.
[/NHL Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WDX7.png)

I have this existing Scores component:

```
function Scores(props) {  

const navigate = useNavigate('/'); 
const handleClick = () => {
let path = '/' + {gameId}; 
navigate(path); 
}

    return (
        
        <Card sx={{ Height: 50, padding: .25, margin: 3 }}>
        <CardActionArea onClick={handleClick}>
        <div className = "">
        <CardContent sx={{ width: 200 }}>

            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Typography component="div" variant="h6">{props.gameStatus}</Typography>
            <Typography>{props.gameDateandTime}</Typography>
            </Stack>

            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Typography fontSize={14} sx={{ paddingTop: 1, paddingBottom: 1 }}>{props.awayTeam}</Typography>
            <Typography fontSize={14} sx={{ paddingTop: 1, paddingBottom: 1 }}>{props.awayPoints}</Typography>
            </Stack>
            
            <Typography>@</Typography>

            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Typography fontSize={14} sx={{ paddingTop: 1, paddingBottom: 1 }}>{props.homeTeam}</Typography>
            <Typography fontSize={14} sx={{ paddingTop: 1, paddingBottom: 1 }}>{props.homePoints}</Typography>
            </Stack>

        </CardContent>    
        </div>
        </CardActionArea>        
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Scores;
```

The `Scores.js` component above is rendered in the NHL route from the screenshot:

```
function NHL(){ 
    var date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day; 

    const [scores, setScores] = useState([{ }]); 

    useEffect(() => {
        let url = "http://localhost:3001/schednhl";
        fetch(url).then(res => {
            if(res.ok) {
                return res.json()
            }
        }).then(jsonRes => setScores(jsonRes)); 
    }, []); 

    return (
        <div className='Home'>
            
            <Banner />

            <Typography variant="h3" align="center" sx={{ paddingTop: 5 }}>Live Games</Typography>
            <hr className="lineRow"></hr>
            
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>

            <div className="scroll-box">
                <div className="scroll-box-wrapper">
                    <div className="scroll-box-container" role="list">
            
            {scores.map((score, index) => {
            if(score.gameDate === date && score.gameStatus === "closed" || score.gameStatus === "inprogress") 
                return ( 
                    <Scores
                      className="scroll-box-item"
                      role="listitem"
                      key={index}
                      id={index}
                      gameDate={score.gameDate}
                      gameStatus={score.gameStatus === "closed" ? "Final" : "Live" }
                      homeTeam={score.homeTeam}
                      homePoints={score.homePoints}
                      awayPoints={score.awayPoints}
                      awayTeam={score.awayTeam}
                      />
            
                );
               })}           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
            </Stack>

            <h3 className="home-header" style={{paddingTop: 10 }}>Upcoming Games</h3>
            <hr className="lineRow" style={{  }}></hr>

            <Grid container spacing={3} direction="row" justifyContent="flex-start">

            {scores.map((score, index) => {
            if(score.gameDate === date && score.gameStatus === "scheduled" || score.gameStatus === "upcoming")
                return (
                    <Scores
                      className="scroll-box-item"
                      role="listitem"
                      
                      key={index}
                      id={index}
                      time={score.gameDateandTime}
                      gameStatus={score.gameStatus === "scheduled" ? "Upcoming" : ""}
                      homeTeam={score.homeTeam}
                      homePoints={score.homePoints}
                      awayPoints={score.awayPoints}
                      awayTeam={score.awayTeam}
                      />   
                ); 
               })}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NHL;
```

How can I access the gameId from the NHL function and use that in my Score component?

Comment: The `NHL` component doesn't appear to have or reference any `gameId` variable. Can you clarify what and where you are trying to access it to be used in the `Score` component?

Comment: Not replying what you asked, but I suggest you to navigate to the URL first, then grab the ID from the URL on the component and fetch server data un that page. That way, you can link directly to a game's specific route from outside, and it'll work ok without depending on the previous page.

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah I realized what I was doing wrong. I created a route in my App.js file to `/nhl/:id` then added in `gameId={score.gameId}` in my `NHL.js` page then just let the path that I was navigating to onClick to be `'/nhl/' + (props.gameId)`. I created a new page called Game Detail that displays the gameId in the URL, which works great. 

I took the `gameId` and passed it to my 3rd party API call and got a cross origin error. I'm wondering should I call the API and display the results from client side or should I do that on the backend with a new express endpoint? @Gonzalingui.

Comment: Long story short, since I am getting this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, I suppose rendering the API response on the frontend might be difficult and maybe not the most secure in the long run, unless I used a proxy service? 
If I am thinking about this right I may need to send the `gameId` to the backend, where I can run an API call like `axios.get(apiendpoint/gameId/apikey=...` generate a response, route it to an endpoint where I can fetch the data from my `gameDetail` component on the frontend.